# Lucene.Net Highlight Not Working

Tags: .net, dll, reference, lucene, lucene.net

I'm trying to highlight the words at searching result.
I' m using Umbraco and Lucene.Net
I installed Lucene.Net Contrib with NuGet and its version is 3.0.3.0
Before installation, version 2.9.4.1 had been installed.
After installation Lucene.Net.Contrib.Highlighter is also added to 'References'
But I can not declare it as using Lucene.Net.Contrib.Highlighter or with different way.
So at some lines are not working as

```
var highlighter = Highlighter(HighlightFormatter, FragmentScorer(searchQuery, highlightField,  searcher));

private QueryScorer FragmentScorer(string searchQuery, string highlightField, IndexSearcher searcher)
{
    Query query =
        GetLuceneQueryObject(searchQuery, highlightField).Rewrite(searcher.GetIndexReader());
    return new QueryScorer(query);
}

HighlightFormatter = new SimpleHTMLFormatter("<em><strong>", "</strong></em> ");
```

For Highlighter, SimpleHTMLFormatter and QueryScorer,
I get '..could not be found(Are you missing a using..)' error

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I got the Lucene.Net highlight project Version 2.9.4.1 and compiled. Lucene.Net.Contrib.Highlighter.dll created and I used it. The problem is solved but I still don' t know are there any other way to solve it.

Comment: I also need Lucene.Net highlight in this version. Could you please share DLL file? :)

Answer (score 2):

In version 2.9.4.1 of the NuGet package Lucene.Net.Contrib the three classes `Highlighter`, `SimpleHTMLFormatter` and `QueryScorer` are declared in the namespace `Lucene.Net.Highlight`.

In version 3.0.3 of Lucene.Net.Contrib the classes were moved to the namespace `Lucene.Net.Search.Highlight`.

You should include `using Lucene.Net.Search.Highlight`. Also check that the references in the project points to the dlls included in version 3.0.3 of the NuGet package. Check the path of the reference - it should be something like

```
   <base>\packages\Lucene.Net.Contrib.3.0.3\lib\net40\Lucene.Net.Contrib.Highlighter.dll
```

and not

```
   <base>\packages\Lucene.Net.Contrib.2.9.4.1\lib\net40\Lucene.Net.Contrib.Highlighter.dll
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, which path should I check for <base>\packages\Lucene.Net.Contrib.3.0.3\lib\net40\Lucene.Net.Contrib.Highlighter.dll I could not find the reference.

Comment: @user1451549: You should find 'Lucene.Net.Contrib.Highlighter' under 'References' in Visual Studio. Right-click and check the value of 'Path'.